# Unable to type anything in spark console

Tags: apache-spark

In my machine when i start SPARK console in command prompt , I am unable to type anything in it. When I type something , It is not visible and when I use `Enter` or `Control + Enter` on it, It shows the result which was typed. But whatever is typed is not visible. 
Please suggest some remedy for this . 
The spark version I am using is `Spark - 1.2.0`
Also It is sowing me this line while starting the spark in command prompt

> Failed to created SparkJLineReader: java io. IOExceptio  : No such file or directory.

Could that be a problem?

[image]

Comment: Can you please change logging level to DEBUG and provide Spark logs? It would be much easier to check what's the cause of your problem :)

Comment: Where did you get Spark 1.2.0, it is not available to download from [download](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) page.

Answer (score -1):

The issue seems to be related to permissions on home directory. The same issue is resolved [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2090)